# how to measure outlier distance in linear regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, measurement, outliers

For example, quantity vs price for a product,
if I found out for specific quantity, the price is off the line too much,
is there any statistics number showing how much difference the point from the regression line in R?

or lets say how to measure the distance from specific point on the graph to the regression line?
Thanks for your input

Comment: Subtraction works pretty well for differences. `predict()` works well for getting the modeled prediction of a point. You can also look at the residuals built in to most model objects.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the residuals.

A residual is defined as
`e = y - ŷ`

You can get them on R by doing

```
M <- lm(a~b)
M$residuals
```

Although, geometrically speaking, this would be a vertical distance to the line, orthogonal to the x axis, and not a distance from the observed point to the closest point on the line, which would be orthogonal to the line itself.

Comment: To add to this,if you're looking for a general measure of how good a fit your model is, you could look into the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). Which would be available in R with `summary(M)$r.squared` and `summary(M)$adj.r.squared`. With `summary(M)` in general containing useful information.

Comment: thanks for of you, so how did u determine if that point is really an outlier?

Comment: @user35631 The residual is given for every point in your sample. There isn't a "right way" to determine an outlier. If you want to check for dots that have 'too much residue', you need to define how much is 'too much'. One way to go about it is to find residues that are outside of the interval [Q1-3.5D, Q3+3.5D], where D = Q3-Q1. Where Q1 and Q3 are the first and third quartiles of all the residues. But for example you can change 3.5 to 1.5. It really comes down to picking a definition of outlier. [Outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) for more information.

Comment: @user35631 You seem to be lacking some basic knowledge of R and statistics, and that's okay, everyone's been there. I'd recommend you, however, to try to pursue a more traditional path of learning rather than jumping into the abyss and trying to fill the holes. [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25632/what-book-is-recommendable-to-start-learning-statistics-using-r-at-the-same-time) you can find some book recommendations. To answer your last question, use the function [quantile](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html)